# Линейная функция потерь для интерполяции многочлена

Tags: python

Как провести многочлен одной переменной по заданным точкам в Python, используя при этом в качестве функции потерь не сумму квадратов, а просто расстояния от точек до полинома(по вертикали)?

Answer (score 1):

Интересный вопрос. Есть некоторые идеи на этот счёт, но для начала рассмотрим как работает классический вариант этой задачи - [МНК](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2).

Многочлен имеет вид [image: f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + ... + a_n x^n], данные представляют из себя набор точек - пар координат: [image: (x_0, y_0), (x_1, y_1), ..., (x_k, y_k)].

Рассчитается выражение *S* - сумма квадратов отклонений (у нас там будут модули, но позже) набора точек от многочлена (зависящего от набора неизвестных коэффициентов [image: a_i]), затем вычисляются те значения коэффициентов, при которых сумма будет минимальна. Это достигается в точке, где все частные производные
[image: \partial S \over \partial a_i]
будут равны 0. Итак:

[image: S = \sum_{j=0}^{k} (f(x_j) - y_j)^2]

[image: \frac{\partial S}{\partial a_i}=\frac{\partial S}{\partial f}\cdot\frac{\partial f}{\partial a_i} = \sum_{j=0}^{k}2\cdot(f(x_j) - y_j)\cdot x_j^i = 0]

Эти выражения составляют систему из *n* линейных уравнений относительно неизвестных коэффициентов [image: a_i] которые отсюда лего находятся, например, с помощью `numpy.linalg.solve`

В нашем же случае в выражении для *S* вместо квадрата стоит модуль:

[image: S = \sum_{j=0}^{k} |f(x_j) - y_j|]

И, значит

[image: \frac{\partial S}{\partial a_i} = \sum_{j=0}^{k}sgn(f(x_j) - y_j)\cdot x_j^i = 0]

Где *sgn(x)* формально производная модуля: -1 при x < 0 и 1 при x > 0. Теперь это система из *n* уже непонятно-каких уравнений относительно [image: a_i].
Наверняка эти коэффициенты можно найти каким-нибудь итерационным методом, но вот я пока не знаю как.

Надеюсь мои замечания были полезны. Может кто-нибудь ещё подскажет как продолжить?

Answer (score 1):

В `scipy` есть универсальная функция вычисления минимума [`scipy.optimize.minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html)

Эта функция ищет локальный экстремум в `n`-мерном пространстве и никак не зависит от физического смысла этого экстремума.

Соответственно, если есть потребность посчитать аппроксимацию по какой-нибудь нестандартной норме, достаточно написать функцию, которая принимает параметры модели, вычисляет норму между моделью и заданными значениями, и эту норму возвращает.

Например, функция, возвращающая расстояние между полиномиальной аппроксимацией и заданными точками по норме 'средний модуль расстояния':

```
# расстояние между полиномом и заданными точками
# р - вектор коэффициентов полинома, старший коэффициент с индексом 0
def poly_model_lindiff(xdata, ydata, p):
    y = np.polyval(p, xdata)
    return np.abs(y-ydata).sum()/len(xdata)

# построение модельной функции для заданных точек
def mk_lin_model(xdata, ydata):
    return lambda p: poly_model_lindiff(xdata, ydata, p)
```

Соответственно, минимизационная задача решается в пространстве параметров `p`. Например, аппроксимация кубическим полиномом:

```
linres = spo.minimize(mk_lin_model(xdata, ydata), (1,-1,1,-1))
```

Кортеж `(1,-1,1,-1)` означает, что поиск экстремума начинается с полинома `x^3 - x^2 + x - 1`

[Пример аппроксимации синуса кубическим полиномом в Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1bipnXILNzy0hzvolK1cEXcV0lyGvnxjP?usp=sharing). В этом примере ищутся как аппроксимация в смысле наименьших модулей, так и аппроксимация в смысле минимальных квадратов. Разница только в минимизируемой функции, а техника одна и та же.

Answer (score 0):

Такая метрика не может выступать в роли функции потерь.

Возьмем вот такие три точки. Минимизируя "просто расстояние", можно провести бесконечное количество регрессионных прямых, причем для каждой из них значение функции потерь будет равно 0.

Если точек будет больше, и расположены они будут не так симметрично, то все равно можно минимизировать функцию потерь до 0, просто проведя прямую, параллельную оси Х, через геометрический центр облака точек.

Про использование модуля (абсолютного значения) расстояния см. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46019/why-squared-residuals-instead-of-absolute-residuals-in-ols-estimation

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И каким же образом сумма расстояний по вертикали стала равна 0, если мы складываем 3 неотрицательных числа (это же расстояния), при том, что мы не сможем провести прямую, где все эти расстояния равны 0?

Comment: Расстояние в данном случае (как сформулировано в вопросе) - это разность значений ординаты для исходной точки и для точки на кривой, находящейся "напротив нее по вертикали". "От точки до полинома по вертикали" для нарисованных трех точек получаются расстояния: h, 0, -h. Правильнее было бы назвать это отклонением, но я вопрос вот так понял.

Comment: Функция потерь по определению характеризует расхождения (отклонения) подогнанных значений от фактических, поэтому нужно брать абсолютное значение. Тогда имеем дело с функцией потерь наименьших модулей (LAD score), реализация есть, например, в http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor.html. Кстати, такая функция потерь вроде как все равно не гарантирует единичность решения.

Comment: И всё же расстояние по вертикали (как сформулировано в вопросе) - это именно модуль разности. Расстояние по определению отрицательным не бывает. А вот насчёт единственности решения - согласен, проблема.

Answer (score 0):

Поставленный вопрос формулируется как метод наименьших модулей (МНМ). По сравнению с МНК он даёт решение более грубое, но и более устойчивое к ошибкам в исходных данных.

В частности, полином нулевого порядка - это медиана значений ординат, для которой при нечётном количестве точек решение единственно, а при чётном - представляет собой интервал между парой "внутренних" точек.

Коэффициенты, минимизирующие невязку
**ε = ∑<sub>(i=0…n-1)</sub> |y<sub>i</sub> - ∑ a<sub>k</sub>φ<sub>k</sub>(x<sub>i</sub>)|**,
можно найти "в лоб" по методу интервалов, рассматривая 2<sup>n</sup> сочетаний знаков s<sub>i</sub> для каждого из n модулей-слагаемых невязки:
**min<sub>(a<sub>k</sub>)</sub> ε = min<sub>(a<sub>k</sub>, s<sub>i</sub>)</sub> Φ(a<sub>k</sub>, s<sub>i</sub>)**,
где
**Φ(a<sub>k</sub>, s<sub>i</sub>) = min<sub>(a<sub>k</sub>)</sub>∑<sub>(i=0…n-1)</sub> s<sub>i</sub>(y<sub>i</sub> - ∑ a<sub>k</sub>φ<sub>k</sub>(x<sub>i</sub>))**.

Таким образом, каждый заданный набор знаков {s<sub>i</sub>} порождает задачу линейного программирования на минимизацию целевой функции
**Φ(a<sub>k</sub>, s<sub>i</sub>)**,
линейной относительно коэффициентов a<sub>0</sub>,… a<sub>n-1</sub>.
Ограничения имеют вид
**s<sub>i</sub>(y<sub>i</sub> - ∑ a<sub>k</sub>φ<sub>k</sub>(x<sub>i</sub>)) >= 0.**
Поскольку коэффициенты s<sub>i</sub> = ± 1 - это просто заданные знаки, то система ограничений тоже линейна.
Такая задача может иметь произвольное число решений или не иметь их вообще. Очевидно, что для неё существуют варианты готовых решений.

Глобальный минимум невязки по всем таким задачам определяет требуемый вектор решения {a<sub>k</sub>}.

Для поставленной задачи **φ<sub>k</sub>(x) = x<sup>k</sup>**.